# What happen with my InvokedRequired?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, invokerequired

What wrong with my code ??

Why it not go to true statement ?

[image]

Comment: Is _main.InvokeRequired true as well?

Comment: oh my wrong :( You can see my highlight and I added to watch but it only happen with 2 statement. So, VS can not support add to watch more than 1 line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement has *three* conditions - you're only showing *two* of them in the debugger.

I suspect that explains why you're seeing something odd - but I don't think your code is appropriate to start with. For one thing, you're testing the same condition twice, which is pointless (did you mean one of them to be `lockScreen` rather than `loginScreen`?) - but more importantly, if *one* of those `InvokeRequired` properties returns false, you won't be using `BeginInvoke` for *any* of the forms... even if `InvokeRequired` returned true for that form.

I suggest you split this up into three separate blocks, each of which checks and acts on a single form.

Answer (score 1):

the third statement in the IF is a different boolean :)