# What is wrong with my InvokeRequied #2?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, invokerequired

The first topic is [What wrong with my InvokeRequied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945829/what-happen-with-my-invokedrequired)

I followed the answer that he recommended it to me but I found a new problem.

The result of below picture is cross thread exception.

What is wrong with my code ?

How to solve this problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) `InvokeRequired` can return `false` even in cases where `InvokeRequired` should be `true` - namely in the case that you access `InvokeRequired` before the `Handle` of that control/form (or a parent of it) has been created.

Basically your check is incomplete which leads to the result you see.

You need to check [`IsHandleCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.ishandlecreated.aspx) - if that is `false` then you would need to use `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` regardless of what `InvokeRequired` returns.

[UPDATE]
**BUT**:
This usually won't work robustly since `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` check which thread created `Handle` to do their magic...
[/UPDATE]

Only if `IsHandleCreated` is `true` you act based on what `InvokeRequired` returns - something along the lines of:

```
if (control.IsHandleCreated)
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
}
else 
{ 
    // in this case InvokeRequired might lie - you need to make sure that this never happens! 
    throw new Exception ( "Somehow Handle has not yet been created on the UI thread!" );
}
```

[UPDATE]

**Thus the following is important to avoid this problem**

Always make sure that the `Handle` is already created BEFORE the first access on a thread other than the UI thread.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx) you just need to reference `control.Handle` in the UI thread to force it being created - in your code this must happen BEFORE the very first time you access that control/form from any thread that is not the UI thread.

[/UPDATE]

Comment: IsHandleCreated is false and after call BeginInvoke it catch an exception. "Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created."

Comment: Solved !! My UI Thread is not create. I just put some delay before call this function and it's works !